# File upload keeps crashing for larger files - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am using React for the front end using Axios to make a post request to send files with form data.... 
But if the file size is around 5 to 10 MB it sometimes crashes

```
var multer = require("multer");
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "public/uploads");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
});

module.exports = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post("/", auth.isAdmin, upload.array("files", 5), (req, res) => {
console.log(req.files);
})
```

The console shows the file information but the app keeps crashing... I cannot seem to figure out why... sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.
I think it has something to do with the file size

Answer (score 0):

you can improve limits :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb', extended: true}))    
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb', extended: true}))
```

and :

```
var storage = multer({storage: storage, limits: {fileSize: 10MB, 
fieldSize: 10MB}}).diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) { ...
```

Comment: can i do more than 10mb say like upto 50mb

Comment: Yeah. You can change the values and check whether it is working.

Comment: Accept the answer if it works. So others with the same problem can tryout